# Sending smtp email via mail gem results in 554 5.7.0 Reject

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, mail-gem

I'm trying to send emails from a rails application using smtp. Sending the emails does not cause problems, but some recipients do not receive the emails. Instead, delivery notices ("Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender") are returned with:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 5.7.0 Reject, id=04635-09 - spam: This message was
   blocked for security reasons
```

Now the strange part:

- Sending a test mail through a mail client via smtp (TLS/SSL true, port 465, auth: password) works. The recipient receives the email without error.
- Sending the email via `sendemail -o tls=yes -f foo@fiedlschuster.de -t bar@example.com -s 212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de -xu foo@fiedlschuster.de -xp password -u "Hello from sendemail" -m "This is a test." -vvvv` works. The recipient receives the email without error.
- Sending the email through the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) (which is what I want to achieve) using the same smtp account works, but the recipient does not receive the email. Instead, "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" is sent to the sender address.

  ```
  require 'mail'

  options = {address: "212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de", user_name: "foo@fiedlschuster.de",
      password: "...", authentication: "login"}

  Mail.defaults { delivery_method :smtp, options }

  message = Mail.new(to: "bar@example.com", from: "foo@fiedlschuster.de",
      subject: "Test", body: "This is a test.")
  message.deliver
  ```

  Also, I've tried these options, resulting in the same issue:

  ```
  options = {address: "212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de", user_name: "foo@fiedlschuster.de",
      password: "...", authentication: "login"}

  options = {address: "212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de", user_name: "foo@fiedlschuster.de",
      password: "...", authentication: "login",
      enable_starttls_auto: true}

  options = {address: "212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de", user_name: "foo@fiedlschuster.de",
      password: "...", authentication: "login",
      port: 465, enable_starttls_auto: false, ssl: true}

  options = {address: "212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de", user_name: "foo@fiedlschuster.de",
      password: "..."}
  ```

Does this make sense to anyone?

### Additional information

#### MX records

```
▶ host -t MX fiedlschuster.de
fiedlschuster.de mail is handled by 10 mail.fiedlschuster.de.

▶ host -t MX 212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de
212-227-10-158.benjaminkant.de has no MX record
```

Comment: Who knows? You haven’t provided any code to reproduce the error or any information about your MX records or other DNS security records.

Comment: Thank you for requesting specific information that could help narrowing the issue down rather than downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's worth checking `message.to_s`

```
Date: Wed, 24 Jul 2019 17:15:08 +0100
From: foo@fiedlschuster.de
To: bar@example.com
Message-ID: <5d38840ce52e9_5a6a2af20734c5b418642@my-machine-name.mail>
Subject: Test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a test.
```

The only thing that screams out at me is the Message-ID - it uses your machine name. It's possible that some spam filters compare this to the sender's domain name, and if they don't match, assume that you are a bot?

(I don't know what `sendemail` does here, but my Thunderbird certainly uses my domain name)

So I'd try:

```
message = Mail.new(to: "bar@example.com", from: "foo@fiedlschuster.de",
    subject: "Test", body: "This is a test.", message_id: "#{Mail.random_tag}@fiedlschuster.de")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, changing the message id does not resolve the issue. In fact, the message id created by `sendemail` (which leads to a delivery without error) is also not corresponding to the domain of the smtp server: `Message-ID: <908248.570139648-sendEmail@fiedl-mbp>`. The message id does not appear to be the problem.